# Hibernate first level cache to hold entities found by a property that is not the ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, caching

I am working on a Java 8 / Spring Boot 2 application and I have noticed that the security module of my app internally uses the `findByEmail` method of my `UserRepostiory` (which is a standard Spring Data JPA Repository). When I enabled Hibernate SQL logging, I discovered that these queries are performed multiple times within the same session (security uses it 3-4 times and then my business code uses it some more times). Each time the query hits the database. 
This surprised me, as I expected it to be cached in the Hibernate's first level cache. After reading up about it a little bit more, I found out that the first level cache only caches the result of the `findById` query, not others.

Is there anyway that I can cache the result of the `findByEmail` query in the first level cache? (I don't want the cache to be shared between sessions, I don't want to use the 2nd level cache, as I think it should be invalidated right after the current session ends).

Comment: You can try hibernate.cache.use_query_cache and while generating query add .setCacheable(true)

Comment: I did try using this, so basically setting up a second level cache, but it would not be invalidated at the end of session

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cache the results of a query on a unique property if you annotate the property with the `@NaturalId` annotation. If you then use the dedicated API to execute the query, the results will be stored in the 1st level cache. An example:

```
User user = entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .bySimpleNaturalId(User.class)
    .load("john@example.com");
```